# Let $f:\Bbb X\subset\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ define continuous function. Prove that $f_-(x)$ and $f_+(x)$ are continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

> Let $f(x)$ define a continuous function on some interval $\Bbb X$. Prove that the following functions are continuous in $\Bbb X$:
>   $$
> f_+(x) = \begin{cases}
> \begin{align}
> f(x),\ &f(x) > 0 \\
> 0,\ &f(x) \le 0
> \end{align}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   $$
> f_-(x) = \begin{cases}
> \begin{align}
> 0,\ &f(x) \ge 0 \\
> f(x),\ &f(x) < 0
> \end{align}
> \end{cases}
> $$

It looks like if we sum up both functions we eventually get $f(x)$ itself, so:
$$
f(x) = f_-(x) + f_+(x)
$$

My main idea was to arrive at a contradicton. The function is either continuous or discontinuous so we have $4$ possible cases:

1. Both $f_-(x)$ and $f_+(x)$ are continuous
2. Both $f_-(x)$ and $f_+(x)$ are discontinuous
3. $f_-(x)$ is continuous and $f_+(x)$ is discontinuous
4. $f_-(x)$ is discontinuous and $f_+(x)$ is continuous

I've proven a while ago that if a function $f$ is continuous and $g$ is discontinuous at some point then $f+g$ is also discontinuous at that point. That means for cases $3$ and $4$:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) = f_-(x) + f_+(x) \iff f(x) - f_-(x) = f_+(x)\tag 3\\
f(x) = f_-(x) + f_+(x) \iff f(x) - f_+(x) = f_-(x)\tag 4
\end{align*}
$$
So we have arrived at a contradiction by the sum of continuous function must be continuous. By this we're left with cases $1$ and $2$.

Unfortunately, I couldn't eliminate case $2$ because the sum of discontinuous functions may be either continuous or discontinuous.

Is it possible to apply similar reasoning to eliminate case $2$? If not how do I show what's asked in the problem statement?

Comment: Can you use the fact that the composition of continuous functions is continuous?

Comment: @eranreches Yes, I've proven that recently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that $g\left(x\right)=\max\left\{0,x\right\}$ (and similarly $\min$) is continuous. This is much simpler. Now use composition.

Comment: What a neat observation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$f_+(x)=\max\{0,f(x)\}=\frac12 (f(x)+|f(x)|),$$ which is continuous as a sum of continuous functions.